# c# Chart y-axis scaling uniformly

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm using a device that receives a pressure reading in a 4-20MA, converts it to a voltage and scales that within a range and then charts the data in a line graph, live. I am scaling the y-axis and have buttons in place to adjust the y-axis scale during runtime depending on how big the range is needed. So in otherwords, if the pressure starts at 0 psi, then jumps all the way to 20,000, I want the chart to show -100 (minimum - only so that if PSI is at 0, its visible) to 0, 100, 200, ..., 19800, 19900, 20000. But instead if pressure is at say 19743, the scale is "-43, 43, 143, ..., 19843, 19943" something like that. Is there a way to change this so it only counts by "whole hundreds" or something?

My y-axis interval is jumping by 50's so the axis can go 0, 50, 100,... or 0, 100, 200, etc. and so on (Able to jump 500 psi at a time if desired). But I just want to y-axis numbers to show whole hundreds, if that makes sense.

My maximum y-value is the max incoming value (I'm comparing 3 input values) and adding 1,000 to that. So if the current max pressure is 19,000 psi, the chart should show -100 to 20,0000.

My comparisons of incoming values - The names are "RawIn#" but these are already scaled. Bad variable naming, I know.

```
        if (rawIn0 > rawIn1)
        {
            maxY = Convert.ToInt32(rawIn0);
        }
        else if (rawIn1 > rawIn0)
        {
            maxY = Convert.ToInt32(rawIn1);
        }
        if (maxY < rawIn2)
        {
            maxY = Convert.ToInt32(rawIn2);
        }

        if (maxY > absoluteMaxY)
        {
            absoluteMaxY = maxY;
        }

        if (rawIn0 > rawIn1)
        {
            minY = Convert.ToInt32(rawIn1);
        }
        else if (rawIn1 > rawIn0)
        {
            minY = Convert.ToInt32(rawIn0);
        }
        if (minY > rawIn2)
        {
            minY = Convert.ToInt32(rawIn2);
        }
```

The current way I'm scaling the chart. MinY is always 0. So minimum = -100.

```
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = absoluteMaxY + 1000;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = minY - 100;
```

My buttons on runtime to increase and decrease the interval. The higher the // interval, the easier it is to see the entire chart with less y-axis lines.

```
    private void yValueSizeInc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval < 50)
        {
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 50;
        }
        else
        {
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval += 50;
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.pressureInterval = 
        (int)chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval;
        yValueSize.Text = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval.ToString();
    }

    private void yValueSizeDec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval <= 50)
        {
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 50;
        }
        else
        {
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval -= 50;
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.pressureInterval = (int) 
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval;
        yValueSize.Text = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval.ToString();
    }
```

[Pressure count can be seen not uniform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu3W9.jpg)

Comment: When you get your input, divide it by 100 and then multiply it by 100 on an integer variable, example, if the input is 2335, ex: int input=2335; input=input/100*100; input well equal 2300.

Comment: I don't want the input to equal a whole number (xx00, x00, x0, etc). Just the values for the y-axis. The data needs to be precise so it can't be manipulated as continual loss of pressure over time is important.

Comment: So do it only for your scale.

Comment: You set the y-axis interval to 50. Why not 100 ?

Comment: I want the scale to be adjustable. I don't know what pressures the end user will be working with; it can be 3k, 5k, 10k, or 20k pressures so if they're working with 20k, an interval at 50 won't work well, but an interval at 500 would. Having an interval at 100 still goes from (current pressure reading say equals 53) -53, 0, 53, 153, 253, 353, ..., etc.